# Kindle fire bluetooth not working properly?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, kindle-fire

I'm writing an app that connects to bluetooth low energy devices and reads data from them. Specifically, I use the startLeScan() method for BLE scanning. Up to this point I've been using a Kindle Fire for debugging, but BLE scanning has been extremely unreliable. The scanner in the Kindle's wireless settings is able to instantly discover the devices, but in my app, it only discovers the devices about 1/15 times. Furthermore, the results are the same with the sample scanner provided Android, so I'm not sure if it's actually a problem with my code. I've also tested my own app on my friends Samsung Galaxy S7 and it discovered the devices immediately without any problems. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue with the Kindle Fire?

Comment: To be more specific it's a Kindle Fire 5th generation

Answer (score 0):

In talking with customer support at Amazon today, the Kindle Fire does not support BLE.  "Fire tablets run a different hardware and software system that is not the same as Android which is why the Fire devices are unable to support Bluetooth low energy (BLE) devices."